# limits calculation /product

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

Calculate
$\;\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\ldots\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)$

What I have done:

$\left(1-\dfrac{1}{2}\right)\left(1-\dfrac{1}{3}\right)\ldots\left(1-\dfrac{1}{n}\right)=\prod\limits_{i=2}^{n} \dfrac{i-1}{i}$

But after that I am stuck

Comment: $1-\frac{1}{n} =\frac{n-1}{n}$. You might have change insonsitently an $i$ for an $n$.

Comment: @OliverDiaz: thank you, changed it, then everything was wrong. deleted that part

Comment: Now, as with telescopic sums, you would get cancelations.

Comment: $\frac{2}{1}\frac{3}{2}\frac{4}{3}...\frac{n-1}{n-2}\frac{n}{n-1}$. Do you notice the pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite each factor and simplify:
$$\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{3}\Bigr)\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{4}\Bigr)\dots\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n-1}\Bigr)\Bigl(1-\frac{1}{n}\Bigr)=\\=\frac 12\,\frac 23\,\frac34\cdots\frac{n-2}{n-1}\frac{n-1}n=\frac 1n$$

Comment: Perfect, thank you